# How do I use TestFlight with a Swift 1.2 app?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, swift

I've updated my app to use Swift 1.2, which I'm realizing requires Xcode 6.3, which is still in beta. I tried to submit it to TestFlight, but as it's a beta version TestFlight said I couldn't use it for external testing.

How would I go about using TestFlight with my app, while being able to keep all my pretty `as!` statements?

Answer (score 0):

The beta error you are reporting has to do with your provisioning profile.  Make sure your AD-HOC provisioning profile has testflight enabled.

Edit it, enable test flight, Save, Re-download the provisioning profile

Then you will be able to use the iOS TestFlight features on your build.
Do you have any external testers configured in iTunes Connect?  Remember external testers will only be able to test builds that have been "beta reviewed".  If you want to just push builds quickly and get people testing then you have to add them as Internal Testers by adding them to your iTunes connect profile with limited privileges.

Personally I much prefer the way TestFlight used to work but now that I've got my team setup as internal testers and my provisioning profile re-built with the "BETA TestFlight" setting enabled it isn't so bad.

Comment: But this is possible to do with Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2?

Comment: This article https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=02232015d talks about new features in Xcode 6.3 that add debug symbols to testflight. That leads me to believe there is no beta ban on testflight.   Did you check your provisioning profile like I suggested above ?  Remember you need to download it again and make sure you are using the new one to compile your build

Comment: As someone not very well-versed in provisioning profiles, I was under the impression I didn't need a specific provisioning profile, did I? When I got to create a new ad-hoc profile, it asks me to manually select devices, which I was under the impression was not the point of TestFlight.

Comment: The old test flight (when it was not integrated into iTunesConnect)  needed you to manually select the devices on the profile.  The new one doesn't seem to have that requirement.  That was my error.  Make sure you are signing your app with the Ad-hoc profile and not the app-store profile.  I submitted mine with the app-store profile and tried to do test flight and it gave me an error about "Beta test flight" entitlements.  Switching to my ad-hoc profile made it work again.

Comment: Also.  Are you uploading with the "Application Loader" or using Xcode directly?  I found the application loader was selecting my appstore profile by default and I couldn't use that to upload a testflight build.  Instead I created an archive using my adhoc profile and then in Xcode go to WINDOW at the top then ORGANIZER.  Click on your new archive there an Submit.  That uses the correct profile for me.

Comment: You submitted it with Xcode 6.3? I tried switching to ad-hoc and I still get the complaints about using a beta version. I'm using Xcode.